# Install man pages in directory with update-alternatives

Tags: debian, ubuntu, man, alternatives

Using *update-alternatives*(8) on a Debian system it is possible to add man pages as slaves under some master alternative.

For example, the following command installs an alternative man page `tclsh.1` alongside the alternative executable for `tclsh`.

```
$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/tclsh tclsh /usr/bin/tclsh8.6.0 100 \
    --slave /usr/share/man/man1/tclsh.1 tclsh.1 /usr/share/man/man1/tclsh8.6.0.1
```

But what if I have not one but entire directories full of man pages that I want to install as alternatives? How can I add those without adding hundreds of slaves?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install my own [Tcl 8.6](http://www.tcl.tk/) (no ActiveState). It has over 800 man pages under `/opt/tcl8.6.0/man/man[13n]`.

Comment: Something tells me to update `/etc/manpath.config` but I'm not sure if there is an API though docs imply that packages may update it. Though it won't be under *alternatives* control :/